# GET запрос возвращает null

Tags: javascript, api, get

Пытаюсь получить информацию через get запрос, сервер возвращает null.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function whoami() {
  const whoAmiURL = 'https://shikimori.one/api/users/whoami'

  function sendAuth(method, url, WhoAmiData = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhrwhoami = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhrwhoami.open(method, url)
      xhrwhoami.responseType = 'document'

      xhrwhoami.onload = () => {
        if (xhrwhoami.status >= 400) {
          resolve(xhrwhoami.response)
          alert('Упс... чет не так пошло, сейчас попробую получить новый токен')
          // refresh()
        } else {
          resolve(xhrwhoami.response)
        }
      }
      xhrwhoami.onerror = () => {
        reject(xhrwhoami.response)
      }
      xhrwhoami.send(JSON.stringify(WhoAmiData))
    })
  }
  var AcToken = localStorage.getItem('auth');
  var parseAcToken = JSON.parse(AcToken);
  const WhoAmiData = {
    "User-Agent": 's’app',
    "Authorization": parseAcToken,
  }
  sendAuth('GET', whoAmiURL, WhoAmiData)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135267/discussion-on-question-by-sxndwl-get---null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы отправляете запрос так:

```
  // создаете экземпляр
  const xhrwhoami = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // иницализируете
  xhrwhoami.open(method, url)
  // определяете тип ответа
  xhrwhoami.responseType = 'document'
  // коллбек загрузки
  xhrwhoami.onload = () => {
    ...
  }
  // коллбек ошибки
  xhrwhoami.onerror = () => {
    ...
  }
  //отсылаете данные в теле запроса
  xhrwhoami.send(JSON.stringify(WhoAmiData))
```

При чем у `Get` запроса нету тела. Но если посмотреть на `Post`, то запрос который вы отослали будет выглядеть примерно так

```
POST https://shikimori.one/api/users/whoami HTTP/1.1    
{
    "User-Agent": "s’app",
    "Authorization": "Bearer parseAcToken"
}
```

Проблема в том что нучно вот такой запрос (данные которые вы отсылали в теле - отслать в заголовках)

```
GET https://shikimori.one/api/users/whoami HTTP/1.1    
User-Agent: s’app
Authorization: Bearer parseAcToken
```

на js:

```
  // создаете экземпляр
  const xhrwhoami = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // иницализируете
  xhrwhoami.open(method, url)
  // определяете тип ответа
  xhrwhoami.responseType = 'document'
  //задаете хедеры
  xhrwhoami.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', `s’app`)
  xhrwhoami.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${parseAcToken}`)
  // коллбек загрузки
  xhrwhoami.onload = () => {
    ...
  }
  // коллбек ошибки
  xhrwhoami.onerror = () => {
    ...
  }
  //отсылаете запрос
  xhrwhoami.send()
```